# How do I sort a dictionary containing real numbers Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, numbers

I tried sorting my dictionary:

```
def averagefunc():
    global new_d
    avgDict = {}
    for k,v in new_d.items():
        avgDict[k] = sum(v)/ float(len(v))
    avgValue =sorted(avgDict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
    print (avgValue)
    print ("----------")
```

Although It does not sort the dictionary it just prints out unsorted.

new_d stores a dictionary: containing a name and then 3 scores for each name.

```
{'Tom': [4,5,8] ,'Bill': [2,5,7], 'Fred' :[6,8,3]}
```

Comment: Did the error tell you which line of code the error was on?

Comment: What is `sum(v)` doing?

Comment: Are all the values in `new_d` sequences?

Comment: theres something inherently wrong with trying to "sort a dictionary" since dictionaries are an unordered data type.

Comment: I have edited the question also its a turple like object

Comment: @RNar Except [**`OrderedDict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (although it's not 'sorted')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > How do I sort a dictionary

You don't. Dictionaries have no sense of order.

Seems like you are expecting the values in `new_d` to be lists of numbers but at least one of them is not.

**UPDATE**

I tried your updated code, and it works for me:

```
print avgValue
>> [('Bill', 4.666666666666667), ('Fred', 5.666666666666667), ('Tom', 5.666666666666667)]
```

An ordered list of tuples, the first element is the name and the second element is the average.

Comment: sorry I meant a turple

Comment: You edited your question but still not provided info regarding what `new_d` really stores.

Comment: I have provided an explanation now

Comment: I've updated my answer..